# Kafka Schema Registry - The retention policy of the schema topic _schemas is incorrect

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to deploy Schema Registry in Kubernetes. However when I try to create a pod with deployment file, it always restart with the below error :

```
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryInitializationException: Error initializing kafka store while initializing schema registry
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:297)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.initSchemaRegistry(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:73)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.configureBaseApplication(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:88)
        at io.confluent.rest.Application.configureHandler(Application.java:255)
        at io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer.doStart(ApplicationServer.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:43)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.exceptions.StoreInitializationException: The retention policy of the schema topic _schemas is incorrect. Expected cleanup.policy to be 'compact' but it is delete
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.verifySchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:278)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.createOrVerifySchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:179)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.init(KafkaStore.java:121)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:295)
```

I thought kafka cleanup.policy need to be set to "compact" and wrote it in env section of deployment file, but no luck.
My environment includes Kafka 3.2.0, zookeeper 3.7.1, schema-registry 6.1.1 and kubernetes 1.24. Here's what I've done to fix it :

1. Added the below parameters in kafka-broker deployment.

   ```
        - name: KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE
          value: "false"
        - name: KAFKA_LOG_CLEANUP_POLICY
          value: "compact"
   ```
2. Downgraded schema-registry version to 6.0.1 and 5.0.4, with no luck.

Please share your thoughts. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`KAFKA_LOG_CLEANUP_POLICY` is a broker setting for the **broker pods**.

The schema registry pod doesn't use those variables you've shown, and it *should* create the topic with the correct settings, but only if it doesn't already exist.

Based on the error, it does exist, but with the wrong config.

**Option 1**: Set `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC` to some other non-existing topic name.

**Option 2**:

Stop the schema registry pod, then delete and re-create the topic on your own.

```
kafka-topics --bootstrap-server <kafka-address> \
  --create --topic _schemas --partitions=1 --replication-factor=3 \
  --config cleanup.policy=compact
```

Then start the registry pod.

I would also suggest upgrading to a later 7.x release.